# data Failed to load configuration: castor.xml.properties

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, marshalling, castor

I'm using castor to marshal the XML which I want to send data as an input parameter to the stored procedure, the method implementation is:

```
private static final String packageName = "/WEB-INF/classes/com/x/y/dao/z/";
    private static Map loadedXmlFiles = new HashMap();

    public static String marshal(String mappingFileName, String rootElement, Object marshalObject){

        Mapping mapping = new Mapping();
        Writer stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        Marshaller marshaller;

        try {
            org.exolab.castor.xml.XMLContext xmlContext = new org.exolab.castor.xml.XMLContext();

            if (!loadedXmlFiles.containsKey(mappingFileName)) {
                mapping.loadMapping(ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext().getResource(packageName + mappingFileName).getURL());
                loadedXmlFiles.put(mappingFileName, mapping);
            }

            xmlContext.addMapping((Mapping)loadedXmlFiles.get(mappingFileName));
            marshaller = xmlContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setRootElement(rootElement);
            marshaller.setSuppressXSIType(false);
            marshaller.setWriter(stringWriter);
            marshaller.marshal(marshalObject);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
```

the problem is in high load (i.e 2800 sessions) this warning appears

```
<message>Failed to load configuration: castor.xml.properties</message>

<stackTrace>
com.xb.eac.commons.util.CastorUtils.marshal(CastorUtils.java:46)\n com.xb.eac.dao.imv.ac.ImvacDaoIbatisImpl.getMainPageProperties(ImvacDaoIbatisImpl.java:80)\n com.xb.eac.dao.imv.ac.ImvacDaoIbatisImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$6c3a52f1.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)\n net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)\n com.xb.commons.logging.handler.ExecutionContextLogHandler.handle(ExecutionContextLogHandler.java:29)\n sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)\n sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)\n java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)\n org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)\n com.xb.eac.dao.imv.ac.ImvacDaoIbatisImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$36fc7437.getMainPageProperties(&lt;generated&gt;)\n com.xb.eac.service.SearchServiceImpl.getMainPageProperties(SearchServiceImpl.java:40)\n com.xb.eac.service.SearchServiceImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$f66d5871.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)\n net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)\n com.xb.commons.logging.handler.ExecutionContextLogHandler.handle(ExecutionContextLogHandler.java:29)\n sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)\n sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)\n java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)\n org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)\n com.xb.eac.service.SearchServiceImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$2de498b7.getMainPageProperties(&lt;generated&gt;)\n com.xb.eac.facade.SearchFacadeImpl.getMainPageProperties(SearchFacadeImpl.java:129)\n com.xb.eac.facade.SearchFacadeImpl$$FastClassByCGLIB$$42f2fbb3.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)\n net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)\n com.xb.commons.logging.handler.ExecutionContextLogHandler.handle(ExecutionContextLogHandler.java:29)\n sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor111.invoke(Unknown Source)\n sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)\n java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)\n org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)\n com.xb.eac.facade.SearchFacadeImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c7a3bf6d.getMainPageProperties(&lt;generated&gt;)\n com.xb.eac.web.action.MainAction.loadImmovables(MainAction.java:108)\n com.xb.eac.web.action.MainAction$$FastClassByCGLIB$$e521866a.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;)\n net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:692)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)\n com.xb.commons.logging.handler.Struts2PresentationLogHandler.handle(Struts2PresentationLogHandler.java:38)\n sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor104.invoke(Unknown Source)\n sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)\n java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)\n org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)\n org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)\n org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:625)\n com.xb.eac.web.action.MainAction$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$7765d25a.loadImmovables(&lt;generated&gt;)\n sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor624.invoke(Unknown Source)\n sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)\n java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:453)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:292)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:255)\n org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)\n org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:211)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:90)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:192)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.xb.eac.web.interceptor.ConversationInterceptor.intercept(ConversationInterceptor.java:42)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.xb.eac.web.interceptor.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:18)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.xb.eac.web.interceptor.UserInterceptor.intercept(UserInterceptor.java:60)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n com.xb.eac.web.interceptor.DataCorrectInterceptor.intercept(DataCorrectInterceptor.java:33)\n com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:249)\n org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)\n org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:510)\n org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)\n org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)\n com.xb.eprocurement.security.tamper.web.TamperingCheckFilter.doFilter(TamperingCheckFilter.java:44)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)\n com.xb.eac.web.action.UrlManageFilter.doFilter(UrlManageFilter.java:49)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:343)\n org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:177)\n com.xb.eac.security.core.user.SwitchUserFilterEx.doFilter(SwitchUserFilterEx.java:29)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)\n org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n com.xb.eac.security.web.authentication.CaptchaVerifierFilter.doFilterInternal(CaptchaVerifierFilter.java:47)\n org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n com.xb.eac.security.web.authentication.CaptchaAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CaptchaAuthenticationFilter.java:59)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:355)\n org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)\n org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)\n org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)\n org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)\n org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:975)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)\n com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)\n com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)\n com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)\n com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)\n com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:87)\n com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)\n com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)\n com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)\n com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)\n com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)\n com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)\n com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)\n com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)\n com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815)\n</stackTrace>
```

Any idea what is the problem?

**Edit: I use Castor-1.2.jar**

Comment: where is xml placed. Is it in jar file  ?

Comment: @MSach xml is in path `/WEB-INF/classes/com/x/y/dao/z/` the name of xml file is an input named `mappingFileName`. Note that at the end I create a war file and install it in web server. If you mean `castor.xml` then I have no idea, I think that's in castor.jar lib, maybe

Comment: i believe path should be com/x/y/dao/z/.

Comment: @MSach If that's the problem, why in few number of sessions there's no warning like this?